# Lua os.execute - specify the path to the file and execute it on the command line

Tags: cmd, lua, operating-system, execute

```
os.execute("start cmd /k cd C:/path/to/js/file/node index.js") 
os.execute("start cmd /k cd C:/path/to/js/file/ & node index.js")
```

I need to execute a node.js script.
This does not work. Help me please!

Comment: I recommend to open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `start /?` and read the output help of this internal command of the Windows command processor `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe`. It would be also a good idea to run `cmd /?` and read the output help in same command prompt window. This looks like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Why is `os.exexute()` used to start `cmd.exe` with option `/c` to run its internal command `start` to start one more instance of `cmd.exe` with option `/k` to change the current directory and ...?

Comment: Well, the command `start` offers already the option `/D` to specify the current directory for the executable to start. The directory separator is ``\`` on Windows and not `/` as on Linux/Mac as described by Microsoft in the documentation about [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file). `C:/path/to/js/file/node index.js` is definitely not the correct full path of a __directory__ to set as current working directory for second `cmd.exe` with its internal command `cd`. Execute `cd /?` for help on this command.

Comment: I suggest to try `os.execute('node "C:\\path\\to\\js\\file\\index.js"')` which should work if `cmd.exe` can find a file with name `node` using the environment variables `PATHEXT` and `PATH` and the JavaScript file `index.js` does not contain code which requires that the current working directory of __node__ executable is the directory containing the file `index.js`.

Comment: But if it is really necessary that the first started `cmd.exe` starts a second `cmd.exe` process to run **node** for processing the JavaScript file `C:\path\to\js\file\index.js` with current working directory set to the directory of the JS script file and keep second `cmd` instance running after finishing execution of **node** while the first `cmd` process closes itself already after starting second `cmd.exe` so that the **Lua** interpreter can continue processing the Lua script while **node** processes parallel the JS script file, then it should be possible to use:

Comment: `os.execute('start "Node for index.js" /D "C:\\path\\to\\js\\file" %ComSpec% /D /K node index.js')` with `%ComSpec%` could be also replaced by `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe`.

Comment: Thanks for helping @Mofi!!!!! It worked! `os.execute('start "Node for index.js" /D "C:\\path\\to\\js\\file" %SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /K node index.js')`

Comment: You better use `os.execute('start "Node for index.js" /D "C:\\path\\to\\js\\file" %SystemRoot%\\System32\\cmd.exe /D /K node index.js')` to specify the Windows command processor correct inside the string in the Lua script file as the backslash character is the escape character in Lua string and for that reason must be escaped with one more backslash to be interpreted as literal character. `Node for index.js` is the title of the opened command prompt window. You can use also a more meaningful title shown also on Windows taskbar on hovering mouse pointer over icon of command prompt.

Comment: I understood. Thanks a lot! @Mofi

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enclose the whole sequence of commands in quotes:

```lua
os.execute('start cmd /k "cd C:/path/to/js/file/ & node index.js"')
```

If the first command is `cd` you can move it into `start /D` option as Mofi pointed out.